# Can I run pre-trained-model on a worse GPU?

Tags: deep-learning

My apologies since my question may sound stupid question. But I am quite new in deep learning.

So basically I used a computer with TITAN X GPU, I created my data set, then I trained it on the TITAN X.

My question is, if I would save this trained model, then load the model on my second computer (which has worse GPU than my TITAN X), then test the model in the new computer - will it go successfully? or the fact that I'm using worse GPU may affect it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it will run slower.
Your model also needs to fit completely into the memory of the older GPU, otherwise you will have a problem running it.
If it runs, however, it should be executed correctly if you are using a modern framework.

Comment: So If my older GPU has 4GB memory, and my data set & trained model are total of 1.3GB , will it run?

Comment: depends on what your network does with the data. 
Usually only a subset of the data will be loaded into memory (a batch).
The model mostly consists of weights, these will be stored on the gpu.
Your model will compute features while processing the data batch, so this takes additional memory on your gpu.

Comment: Also consider the case in which you only use the model for *inference*. If you don't actively train, you also don't have to store activations on the GPU, which can significantly reduce the memory footprint. Convolutional Neural Nets especially take less memory for runtime, see [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2018/slides/lec12.pdf) around slide 30.

Comment: @dennlinger - as I said, the model is already trained. I just need to load it on the worse computer (has 4GB memory on GPU, and the data set & pre-trained-model is of 1.3GB). Training the model on the worse GPU is not necessary for me. Yes- I'm using CNN. So, to sum it up, I'll be able to test the model on the worse GPU?

Comment: Thats difficult to say with the amount of information present. Probably.
You also do not need a gpu per se, you can also run it on the cpu if you do not care about runtime.